# Solr (re)indexing database

Tags: performance, solr, indexing, cron

I've looked for several other questions related to mine but for now I couldn't find a solution for my issue.

Here is the situation:

- A database with table table_x
- A cronjob which checks every 2 minutes to index newly added/updated content in table_x using Solr

Extra information about the cronjob and table_x
- The cronjobs checks a field in table_x to determine if row has to be indexed with Solr or not
- table_x contains over 400k records

What we want is Solr to reindex whole table_x. But there are (we think) 2 factors that are not clear for us:
- What will happen when Solr is indexing all 400k records and the cronjob detects more records to be indexed
- What will happen when a search query is performed on the website while Solr is indexing all 400k records?

If there is someone who can answer this to me?

Kind regards,

Pim

Answer (score 0):

The question has two parts

- What happens to indexing when you see the changes detected while the initial indexing is going on?

  You can make the second cron trigger to wait till the first is completed.        This is more of your application question and how you want to handle it.
- How does query is affected by new indexing or indexing in progress?
  Which version of solr you are using? You can use NearRelaTimeSearch to see the changes before har commits.